# Angular unit test doesn't initialize ag-Grid

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ag-grid

I'm trying to unit test a component that contains an ag-Grid, but the `onGridReady` function never gets called, so all tests involving ag-Grid fail. How can I make onGridReady actually get called before my tests run?

spec file:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorHost<MyComponent>;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  const createHost = createHostFactory({
    component: MyComponent,
    entryComponents: [MyComponent],
    imports: [
      TranslateModule.forRoot(),
      AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
      MatTooltipModule,
      InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
      MaterialModule,
      HMSharedModule,
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: MatDialogRef,
        useValue: [],
      },
      {
        provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
        useValue: [],
      },
      HttpClient,
      HttpHandler,
    ],
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createHost(`<MyComponentSelector></MyComponentSelector>`, {
      hostProps: {},
    });
    fixture = spectator.fixture;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(spectator.component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should detect changes', () => {
    spectator.fixture.detectChanges();

  });
```

"should create" works, but "should detect changes" fails with this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setColumnDefs' of undefined`

in the html, here's my ag-grid:

```
          <ag-grid-angular
            style="height: 157px"
            #agGrid1
            class="ag-grid ag-theme-balham"
            [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs1"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
            (gridSizeChanged)="resizeColumns($event)"
            (cellValueChanged)="updateBottomGrid('agGrid1', false)"
            [singleClickEdit]="true"
          >
          </ag-grid-angular>
```

and here's the onGridReady:

```
  onGridReady(params: any): void {
    console.log('onGridReady called successfully');
    if (this.agGrid1) {
      this.agGrid1.api = params.api;
    }
  }
```

The console statement is never printed, so `onGridReady` is somehow never being called. How can I get it to be called before the unit test?

Edit: Someone mentioned that I need to provide data for columnDefs, but I already have `initializeColumnDefs()` which defines all columns, and I have confirmed that this does get called during the unit test, so this is not the problem.

Also, I don't think this is relevant, but this component is a MatDialog.

Comment: well, the error which is thrown indicates that you are trying to use `setColumnDefs` on undefined/ not initialised variable. It would be helpfull if you provide more code. +probably you will need to set up mock variables for change detection to work correctly

Comment: @lietutis "setColumnDefs" isn't anywhere in my code. The ag-grid api is what is undefined, because it can only be defined by onGridReady, which isn't being called.

Comment: hm, you should look into `ag-grid` lifecycles, I think that the issue is that you need to provide data for *columnDefs* or for other one way bindings :? Thats why you aren't getting console logs, because it's failing before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get rid of this error by adding:

`import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';`

`modules: Module[] = [ClientSideRowModelModule];`

and adding the module in the grid

```
          <ag-grid-angular
            style="height: 157px"
            #agGrid1
            class="ag-grid ag-theme-balham"
            [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs1"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
            (gridSizeChanged)="resizeColumns($event)"
            (cellValueChanged)="updateBottomGrid('agGrid1', false)"
            [singleClickEdit]="true"
            [modules]="modules"
          >
          </ag-grid-angular>
```

I have no idea why that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs on how to use modules: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/. You need to register the modules you wish to use in order to get ag-grid to work.